# maven failure to resolve archetype ear-jee5

Tags: maven, ear, java-ee-5, maven-archetype

I am trying to create an EAR maven module project (in eclipse) with ear-jee5 as the archetype. It fails with the following error.

```
Could not resolve archetype org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:ear-jee5:1.3 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact
Missing org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes:ear-jee5:pom:1.3
```

Could someone please help me resolve this error or show me an alternate way to create the project structure for Maven EAR module?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to create *any* maven archetype, or is that specific one failing?

Comment: It seems the problem is firewall at the office. Adding a mirror not blocked by the firewall solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the failure seems to be because I am behind a proxy/firewall at office. The solution is add proxy configurations or add repository mirrors not blocked by firewall in your settings.xml.

hope this helps someone.

Add proxy

```
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>
```

or mirrors

```
  <mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
  <mirrors>
```

Thanks

Comment: At first I have proxy set up. But it is not working. Then I try to set up the mirror. Then only able to download the archetype. Conclusion is I am required to do both, proxy and mirror. THanks for the hints.